# SQL Multiple Joins on same table with where clause

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2, multiple-columns, where-clause

Folks,

I've had a pretty thorough search before posting and couldn't see this answered anywhere previously. Perhaps it isn't possible.... I'm using SQL server 2008 R2

Anyway, thanks in advance for looking/helping.

I have two tables that I'd like to join.

Table1 (t1):

`Account------Name--------Amount
12345-------account1-----10000.00
12346-------account2-----20000.00`

Table2 (t2):

`ID-----Account---extraData
10-----12345-----ZZ100
20-----12345-----ZZ250
30-----12345-----ZZ400
10-----12346-----ZZ150
20-----12346-----ZZ200`

I'm trying to return the following from the above tables:

`t1.Account---t1.Name------ID1(t2.ID=10)---ID2(td.ID=20)----SUM(Amount)
12345--------account1-------ZZ100------------ZZ250-------------10000.00
12346--------account2-------ZZ150------------ZZ200-------------20000.00`

I have tried various joins of sorts and a union, but can't seem to get the results above. Most result in either nothing, or the Amount column returning as double the required result.

My starting point is:

```
Select t1.Account, t1.Name, t2A.extraData, t2B.extraData, SUM(t1.AMOUNT)
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2A on t1.Account = t2A.Account and t2A.ID = '10'
join table2 t2B on t1.Account = t2B.Account and t2B.ID = '20'
Group by t1.Account, t1.Name, t2A.extraData, t2B.extraData
```

I've reduced the code and complexity of the query for this thread, but the problem is as above. I have no control over the table structure as they form part of an accounting system that I can't amend (I could, but I'd upset one or two people!).

Hopefully I've explained the issue clearly enough. It seems like it should be simple, but I can't seem to fathom it - perhaps I've just been staring too long. Anyway, thanks in advance for your assistance.

Edit: to change the code to reflect the first response highlighting a mistake in my posting.

Comment: hi @RicoS321, why u exclude ID 30?

Comment: I didn't need the data associated with ID 30. I included it in the table to show that there will be multiple IDs, and I wouldn't always want to extract all the data from the table.

Comment: What's the criteria for that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Criteria for what?

Comment: To explain further. The query I added above returns nothing. I'm effectively saying return me some values where ID = 10 and ID = 20. It's like a circular reference, as if the ID is 10, it can't also be 20. Even though, as shown above, it is in my table.

Comment: When I run your query got the same output you given.
Account  Name           ID1 ID2    (No column name)
12345 account1 ZZ100 ZZ250 10000.00
12346 account2 ZZ150 ZZ200 20000.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. I think this helps you to achieve your result.

```
DECLARE @ids varchar(max)
SELECT  @ids=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', [' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10))+']'
         FROM t2
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ')
SELECT @ids
EXECUTE ('SELECT
Account,Name,'+@ids+',Amount
FROM
(SELECT t1.Account,Name,ID,ExtraData,SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM t1 t1 INNER JOIN t2 t2 ON t1.Account=t2.Account
    GROUP BY t1.Account,Name,ID,ExtraData) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(ExtraData)
FOR ID IN ('+@ids+')
) AS PivotTable;')
```